# wso2 ei invoking endpoint with signature

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i starting to use wso2EI in my company. 
We have a requirement to invoke a service that exposes ones of our provider. This service is a SOAP webservice with signature in body through a keystore (they send me a pfx) and the idea is to use the wso2EI to invoke that service to consume internaly through this application.

So, I create a proxy service and the Policy.xml. When i try call the proxy service without the Policy.xml and i put a harcoded request it works fine. But when i put the Policy im facing the following error:

> `[-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-351] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.convertAlias(JavaKeyStore.java:58)
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetCertificateChain(JavaKeyStore.java:163)
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetCertificateChain(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
>           at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetCertificateChain(KeyStoreDelegator.java:101)
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetCertificateChain(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
>           at java.security.KeyStore.getCertificateChain(KeyStore.java:1048)
>           at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoBase.getCertificates(CryptoBase.java:468)
>           at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.prepare(WSSecSignature.java:313)
>           at org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.getSignatureBuilder(BindingBuilder.java:351)
>           at org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.getSignatureBuilder(BindingBuilder.java:266)
>           at org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:762)
>           at org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:457)
>           at org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.build(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:97)
>           at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:147)
>           at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:426)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
>           at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:603)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547)
>           at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:384)
>           at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:123)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:224)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:415)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

The proxy is:

> `<in><header>
>               <sec:OriginPoint xmlns:sec="http://esb.xxx.com/sec/">cd</sec:OriginPoint>
>            </header>
>            <send buildmessage="true">
>               <endpoint>
>                  <address uri="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4443/ESB-Host-secure-services/http/host-secure-services/serviceSecureRouter">
>                     <enableSec policy="gov:ws-policy/Policy.xml"/>
>                  </address>
>               </endpoint>
>            </send>
>         </in>
>         <out>
>            <log level="full"/>
>            <send/>
>         </out>`

and the policy:

> `<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="signingpolicy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
>       <wsp:ExactlyOne>
>           <wsp:All>
>               <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
>                   <wsp:Policy>
>                       <sp:InitiatorToken>
>                           <wsp:Policy>
>                               <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
>                                   <wsp:Policy>
>                                       <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
>                                   </wsp:Policy>
>                               </sp:X509Token>
>                           </wsp:Policy>
>                       </sp:InitiatorToken>
>                       <sp:RecipientToken>
>                           <wsp:Policy>
>                               <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
>                                   <wsp:Policy>
>                                       <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
>                                   </wsp:Policy>
>                               </sp:X509Token>
>                           </wsp:Policy>
>                       </sp:RecipientToken>
>                       <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
>                           <wsp:Policy>
>                               <sp:Basic256Rsa15/>
>                           </wsp:Policy>
>                       </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
>                       <sp:Layout>
>                           <wsp:Policy>
>                               <sp:Strict/>
>                           </wsp:Policy>
>                       </sp:Layout>
>                   </wsp:Policy>
>               </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
>               <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
>                   <wsp:Policy>
>                       <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
>                       <sp:MustSupportRefEmbeddedToken/>
>                       <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
>                   </wsp:Policy>
>               </sp:Wss10>
>               <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
>                   <sp:Body/>
>               </sp:SignedParts>
>           <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
>           <ramp:signatureCrypto>
>               <ramp:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin">
>                   <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</ramp:property>
>                   <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">xx/xx/xx/certificado.jks</ramp:property>
>                   <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">xxx</ramp:property>
>               </ramp:crypto>
>           </ramp:signatureCrypto>
>           </ramp:RampartConfig>
>
>           </wsp:All>
>       </wsp:ExactlyOne>
>   </wsp:Policy>`

**UPDATE**

After setting the org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire with DEBUG option i started to view the resoponse in the log but the servirce continues failing.
The error is this:

> `[2019-03-19 16:29:29,620] [-1] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-2] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:265)
>           at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:124)
>           at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:332)
>           at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:249)
>           at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:221)
>           at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:93)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:263)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

The proxy server is still the same.

**UPDATE 2**
Finally i made it !!!. The problem were  in the proxy service and the security mediator. Here is the final proxy service. Thanks to all!!:

> `<inSequence>
>            <header>
>               <sec:OriginPoint xmlns:sec="http://esb.firstdata.com/sec/">cencosud</sec:OriginPoint>
>            </header>
>            <send>
>               <endpoint>
>                  <address uri="https://172.24.4.215:4443/ESB-Host-secure-services/http/host-secure-services/serviceSecureRouter">
>                     <enableAddressing/>
>                     <enableSec outboundPolicy="gov:ws-policy/Policy.xml"/>
>                  </address>
>               </endpoint>
>            </send>
>         </inSequence>
>      </target>
>      <description/>
>   </proxy>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things stand out to me: It seems, based on the error, that you have some keystore or certificate alias issue. A few things to try:

- A common mistake is to import the certificate without aliasname.
  Inspect the keystore to see if the name is correct.
- I do not see a callbackhandler mentioned? Did you implement one?

Some more info [here](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/ws-security-signing-of-messages) including an [examplepolicy](https://bitbucket.org/Carpentidge/blog_attachments/src/d26d6cdf5f547d42fdd5529857a56b3d5d493bd2/examplepolicy.xml?fileviewer=file-view-default) and [callbackhandler project](https://bitbucket.org/Carpentidge/callbackhandler/src)

Comment: Thanks for the response!!. I made the callback handler and modified my Policy.xml. When i run the webservice now it throw the following error: "Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error in signature with X509Token".

Comment: Difficult to say what is wrong based on just this error. - 100% sure the passwords match? Does the certificate have a private key? Is the folder correct? Try the config on a local instance otherwise. Inspect your keystore using keystoreexplorer.

Comment: Yes, its was the password of the keystore. After that,  i started to receiving this error:[PassThroughMessageProcessor-26] ERROR {org.apac     he.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  Missing wsse:Security header in request
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request.

Comment: Try enabling wire logging (configure->logging->synapse...wire) I suspect this error relates to the response of the service you are calling

Comment: Based on your update, I find the error even stranger. The error seems to refer to an incoming message on the ESB. Did you enable 'security'  on the service?